# How do I convert a pandas pivot table to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to use a pivot table to summarise a dataset and then be able to access the information in the pivot table as if it were a DataFrame.

Consider a hierarchical dataset with patients being treated in a hospital and hospitals situated in regions:

```
import pandas as pd

example_data = {'patient' : ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8','p9','p10','p11','p12','p13','p14','p15','p16','p17','p18','p19','p20','p21','p22','p23','p24','p25','p26','p27','p28','p29','p30','p31','p32','p33','p34','p35','p36','p37','p38','p39','p40','p41','p42','p43','p44','p45','p46','p47','p48','p49','p50','p51','p52','p53','p54','p55','p56','p57','p58','p59','p60','p61','p62','p63'], 
                'hospital' : ['h1','h1','h1','h2','h2','h2','h2','h3','h3','h3','h3','h3','h4','h4','h4','h4','h4','h4','h5','h5','h5','h5','h5','h5','h5','h6','h6','h6','h6','h6','h6','h6','h6','h7','h7','h7','h7','h7','h7','h7','h7','h7','h8','h8','h8','h8','h8','h8','h8','h8','h8','h8','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9','h9'], 
                'region' : ['r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3','r3'] }

example_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(example_data)

print example_dataframe
```

This produces a simple output as follows:

```
   hospital patient region
0        h1      p1     r1
1        h1      p2     r1
2        h1      p3     r1
3        h2      p4     r1
4        h2      p5     r1
5        h2      p6     r1
6        h2      p7     r1
7        h3      p8     r1
8        h3      p9     r1
9        h3     p10     r1
10       h3     p11     r1
11       h3     p12     r1
12       h4     p13     r2
13       h4     p14     r2
14       h4     p15     r2
15       h4     p16     r2
16       h4     p17     r2
etc.
```

Now I want to summarise using a pivot table, simply counting the number of patients in each hospital:

```
example_pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(example_dataframe, values='patient', rows=['hospital','region'], aggfunc='count')

print example_pivot_table
```

This produces the following output:

```
hospital  region
h1        r1         3
h2        r1         4
h3        r1         5
h4        r2         6
h5        r2         7
h6        r2         8
h7        r3         9
h8        r3        10
h9        r3        11
Name: patient, dtype: int64
```

As far as I understand it, this is actually a multi-indexed series.

How can I use this data to find out what region hospital h7 is in? If `hospital`, `region` and the patient count data were separate columns in a DataFrame, it would be easy. But I think hospital and region are indices. I've tried lots of things but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: try [`.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index)

Comment: I had tried .reset_index(inplace=True) but that just produced an error message. However, using .reset_index() worked a treat! Thank you very much for the rapid response.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [get_level_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#reconstructing-the-level-labels) to get the hospital column. You can pass either the number of level or the name of level, i.e. `0` or `hospital`

Then you can get what you want by:

```
In [38]: example_pivot_table[ example_pivot_table.index.get_level_values('hospital') == 'h7' ]
Out[38]: 
hospital  region
h7        r3        9
Name: patient, dtype: int64
```

### Update

To get the regions, you can do

```
example_pivot_table[ example_pivot_table.index.get_level_values('hospital') == 'h7' ]['regions']
```

Comment: Thanks waitingkuo. This isn't quite what I wanted as I wanted to be able to get just the 'r3' bit. However, the method outlined will be very useful in future and it also helps me to understand how data can be manipulated in pandas. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

First up, this isn't a pivot table job, it's a `groupby` job.

Pivot tables are for re-shaping your data when you haven't set an index (see [this doc article](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)), `stack` and `unstack` are for reshaping when you *have* set an index, and `groupby` is for aggregating (which is what this is) and [split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) operations.

Here's how to get your patient counts using `groupby`:

```
>>> patient_count = df.groupby(['hospital', 'region']).count()
>>> print patient_count
                 patient
hospital region         
h1       r1            3
h2       r1            4
h3       r1            5
h4       r2            6
h5       r2            7
h6       r2            8
h7       r3            9
h8       r3           10
h9       r3           11
```

To select certain rows in a multi-index, I usually use `ix` as follows:

```
>>> h7 = patient_count.ix['h7']
>>> print h7
        patient
region         
r3            9
```

And now you can use `get_level_values`

```
>>> h7.index.values[0]
'r3'
```

Or, if you don't want the multi-indexed version (and, for your purposes you probably don't) you can do:

```
>>> patient_count = patient_count.reset_index()
```

Which allows you to find which region hospital `h7` is in as follows:

```
>>> patient_count.region[patient_count.hospital == 'h7']
6    r3
Name: region, dtype: object
```

If you just want `r3` you can do:

```
>>> patient_count.region[patient_count.hospital == 'h7'].values[0]
'r3'
```

Note that `reset_index` doesn't happen in-place which makes it great for chaining methods like this:

```
>>> patient_count.ix['h7'].reset_index().region[0]
'r3'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. That's very helpful. But I don't quite understand the difference between a pivot table and group by. When should each be used?

Comment: @user1718097 I've updated the answer to reflect my attempt to answer your comment question.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick :

```
levels = example_pivot_table.columns.levels
labels = example_pivot_table.columns.labels
example_pivot_table.columns = levels[1][labels[1]]
example_pivot_table.reset_index(inplace=True)
example_pivot_table
```

So,find the levels and labels in your pivot table assign column names and reset index in it. The final result should be the result dataframe of the pivot.